# Python stdout not printing or saving

Tags: python

I am trying to save the text messages from the child process in a variable but they are not saved, also they are not printing anymore. Can someone explain me why because I am confused:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import re

locationOfFile='C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\..........txt'

command="cmd"
subprocess.Popen(command)

process="mycommand"

command3=subprocess.Popen(process, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

#Usially with this command in the child process I  receave many messages, but with stdout I dont see them. I dont want to hide them from the console, just to go in that variable as a string "resultt"
resultt=command3.communicate()

print(resultt)
#But it is not printing?
```

Comment: Does the process ever finish running? A [mcve] would help.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `mycommand`? When I replace it with a simple command (e.g. `ls` or `dir` in windows I guess), it seems to be working. However, I tested it in Linux.

Comment: Perhaps `mycommand` is sending its output to STDERR instead of STDOUT?

Comment: You are not testing the return code, so you don't know if `mycommand` is succeeding. Check that `mycommand` is working when you type it from the command line, and that you are not making unfounded assumptions about the directory that `Popen()` is running it in. Or capture and check `stderr` in your program.